# What is the best way to have a specific css file for a specific html file?

Tags: html, css, sass, project-structure

I've strcutured my web project with sass 7-1 pattern, like this in the picture below:

[image]

My question is that which `css` file/files should I import in each individual `html` file, or to be precise, what `css` file should i have for each `html` file.

for exmaple: `todo-list.html`, should I have an idividual `app.scss` file, which imports neccessary `scss` files for each `html` file and then have them transpiled to a `css` file which is to be imported in that current html file, or; should I have a main `css` file which holds all of the `html` files styles which this current project has (a css file which hold all of the styles for entire web project, including `todo-list.html` styles and `index.html` styles together)?

Comment: Is there any good reason to not use one single CSS file for your whole application?

Comment: @NicoHaase avoiding code conflicts I guess, or NOT having unused css code for each html file